Is SCR Ratio ill defined ? Is there risk of infinite Ratio?
In the rate risk module of Solvency II, the SCR can be simplified in the scenario of single asset vs single liability as the impact of a parallel shock in interest rate.
Approximately  by :
SCR = Shock x ( asset_DV01 - liability_DV01)
Besides that, the SCR ratio can be conceptualized in this case as :
SCR Ratio = Own Funds / SCR = (Asset - Liability) / {Shock x ( asset_DV01 - liability_DV01)}
This can lead to:

A risk of an infinite SCR ratio when the DV01s perfectly match, as the denominator becomes zero.

=> How should the rate risk module handle these scenarios to avoid unrealistic results, and are there practical solutions or regulatory adjustments to address this "infinite SCR" risk? Are regulators aware of it ?
Also it Leads to :

A bell-shaped SCR profile, where the SCR is infinite at the point of perfect duration match and decreases symmetrically with rate moves around that point.

=> Practically,  do we observe the Bell shape of SCR Ratio of insurers with regards to rates moves ?  Even if I believe the risk of infinite SCR ratio for rate risk should be diluted with the addition of the other risk modules.

If SCR is zero and Own Funds positive, where is the "risk" in that? Just write #Inf in the reporting sheet and be done with it.
